# how to add dependence to static library in binding.gyp node-gyp for node.js extension

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I have a simple binding.gyp file for building my node.js extension. I want to change the linking method of the library "mylib" and link it statically instead of using shared library.

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "myext",
      "sources": [
        "code/main.cpp",
        "code/load.cpp",
        "include/load.h"
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "include", "../Library/include"
      ],
      "libraries": [
        "-lmylib", "-L/home/admin/MyLib/Library/binaries/linux/Release"
      ],
      "cflags!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
      "cflags": [ "-std=c++11" ],
      "cflags_cc!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The static and shared versions of mylib are in the same directory:

```
# ls /home/admin/MyLib/Library/binaries/linux/Release
libmylib.a libmylib.so
```

I want to link statically to avoid library installing/loading issues.

Answer (score 9):

You could have node-gyp insert the path for you with the built in variable `module_root_dir`
If I interpret your code correctly, changing your `libraries` to e.g.:

```
"libraries": [
    "-lmylib",
    "-L<(module_root_dir)/../Library/binaries/linux/Release"
],
```

might do the trick. Though I'm not sure if it will link with the `.a` or `.so` version, to specify that you could try:

```
"libraries": [
    "<(module_root_dir)/../Library/binaries/linux/Release/libmylib.a"
],
```

with**out** the **`-L`** prefix and `-lmylib`. Further more, I'm a bit unsure if you're allowed to traverse above the root directory though. I have not tested using anything above the module root directory before. Other than that you should be good to go.

Answer (score 6):

Just add the path of static .a or .so file in the "libraries" section,

"libraries": [ "/usr/local/lib/libnetfilter_queue.so.1.3.0" ]

Comment: It seems that path in "libraries" should be absolute path, is that true?

Comment: @Vimos, you can write like this: "libraries": [ "-Wl,-rpath, mylib.a" ] . This can work.